# Leetcode spiral matrix

Tags: python, c++, programming-challenge

[Link here](https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix/)

I'll include a solution in Python and C++ and you can review one. I'm mostly interested in reviewing the C++ code which is a thing I recently started learning; those who don't know C++ can review the Python code. Both solutions share similar logic, so the review will apply to any.

---

### Problem statement

> Given an m x n matrix, return all elements of the matrix in spiral order.

**Example1:**

[image: spiral1]

```
Input: matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Output: [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]
```

**Example2:**

[image: spiral2]

```
Input: matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
Output: [1,2,3,4,8,12,11,10,9,5,6,7]
```

For some reason c++ execution time is 3x python's time 10 seconds and 28 seconds for python and c++ respectively, same as my recent [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252507/leetcode-group-anagrams) I'm expecting c++ code to be a lot faster, why is it taking so long with both implementations being almost similar as both use the same recursive algorithm.

`spiral_matrix.py`

```
from time import perf_counter


def calculate(matrix):
    numbers = []
    if not matrix or not matrix[0]:
        return numbers
    elif isinstance(matrix[0], int):
        return numbers + matrix
    else:
        if len(matrix) == 1:
            return numbers + matrix[0]
        if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
            return numbers + [item.pop() for item in matrix]
    numbers += matrix[0][:-1]
    numbers += (cols := [*zip(*matrix)])[-1][:-1]
    numbers += matrix[-1][::-1][:-1]
    numbers += cols[0][::-1][:-1]
    if rest := matrix[1:-1]:
        return numbers + calculate([item[1:-1] for item in rest])
    return numbers


def time_spiral(n, matrix):
    print(f'Calculating time for {n} runs ...')
    t1 = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(n):
        calculate(matrix)
    print(f'Time: {perf_counter() - t1} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mtx = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
        [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
    ]
    print(calculate(mtx))
    time_spiral(1000000, mtx)
```

**Results:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 25, 19, 13, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 17, 23, 29, 28, 27, 26, 20, 14, 15, 16, 22, 21]
Calculating time for 1000000 runs ...
Time: 9.450265422000001 seconds
```

`spiral_matrix.h`

```
#ifndef LEETCODE_SPIRAL_MATRIX_H
#define LEETCODE_SPIRAL_MATRIX_H

#include <vector>

std::vector<int> get_spiral(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix);

#endif //LEETCODE_SPIRAL_MATRIX_H
```

`spiral_matrix.cpp`

```
#include "spiral_matrix.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


static void
add_borders(size_t start_width, size_t start_height, std::vector<int> &numbers,
            const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix) {
    for (size_t i{0}; i < start_width - 1; ++i) {
        numbers.push_back(matrix[0][i]);
    }
    for (size_t i{0}; i < start_height - 1; ++i) {
        numbers.push_back(matrix[i][start_width - 1]);
    }
    for (size_t i{start_width - 1}; i > 0; --i) {
        numbers.push_back(matrix[start_height - 1][i]);
    }
    for (size_t i{start_height - 1}; i > 0; --i) {
        numbers.push_back(matrix[i][0]);
    }
}


static std::vector<std::vector<int>> get_rest(size_t start_width, size_t start_height,
const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> rest;
    for (size_t i{1}; i < start_height - 1; ++i) {
        std::vector<int> row;
        for (size_t j{1}; j < start_width - 1; ++j) {
            row.push_back(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        rest.push_back(row);
    }
    return rest;
}


std::vector<int> get_spiral(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &matrix) {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    if (matrix.empty() || matrix[0].empty())
        return numbers;
    if (matrix.size() == 1)
        return matrix[0];
    if (matrix[0].size() == 1) {
        for (auto i: matrix)
            numbers.push_back(i[0]);
        return numbers;
    }
    auto start_width = matrix[0].size();
    auto start_height = matrix.size();
    add_borders(start_width, start_height, numbers, matrix);
    auto rest = get_rest(start_width, start_height, matrix);
    auto next_result = get_spiral(rest);
    numbers.insert(numbers.end(), next_result.begin(), next_result.end());
    return numbers;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix{{1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6},
                                         {7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12},
                                         {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18},
                                         {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
                                         {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
                                         {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36}};
    auto result = get_spiral(matrix);
    for (int num: result)
        std::cout << num << ' ';
    size_t n_times{1000000};
    std::cout << "\nCalculating time for " << n_times << " runs ..." << '\n';
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (n_times > 0) {
        get_spiral(matrix);
        n_times--;
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
            t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << duration << " seconds";
}
```

**Results:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 12 18 24 30 36 35 34 33 32 31 25 19 13 7 8 9 10 11 17 23 29 28 27 26 20 14 15 16 22 21 
Calculating time for 1000000 runs ...
28 seconds
```

Comment: Which options are you using for compilation ? With -O3 and -ffast-math, I get the result in 839 ms ! I paid attention to use the intermediate output of the function, to be sure that the optimiser was not cancelling everything

Comment: @Damien I'm not sure of that because I run the code in the editor (clion) I also tried from the command line: `g++ spiral_matrix.cpp --std c++2a -o spiral_matrix` I then run the executable file and get the same results. How can I check what you're asking for?

Comment: Just use `g++ -O3 -ffast-math spiral_matrix.cpp --std c++2a -o spiral_matrix` for compiling

Comment: @Damien It's down from 24 seconds to 5 seconds, isn't this still slow? I'm running this on my i5 mbp. What are these flags? and how can I adjust editor settings accordingly? is there some kind of documentation to these things?

Comment: I have a i7. You can get details about these options at official gcc documention, for example, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). For compilation, I always use a command line, or a makefile (linux)

Comment: @Damien Here's the current [makefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uztupo4wJ_G8Z9iglCk3H0wtMA7ekPTU/view?usp=sharing) which is auto-generated by clion if you want to check. And I'll check the docs, thanks but still I'm not sure what should / shouldn't be modified as I'm still new to these things.

Comment: I am only using home-made makefile. I don't know clion. I guess the compilation options must be modified by a menu, cannot help on it, sorry.

Comment: @Damien First of all, it is not floating point code, so --fast-math makes no difference. Secondly, never use -O3 by default. It does not guarantee faster code than -O2 optimized  (I've seen several counterexamples) , and there is higher chance to hit a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @llkhd so what do you suggest to improve performance?

Comment: @Ilkhd My makefile use these options by default. I have worked on time critical simulation chains for decades (telecommunications) and always found O3 is faster, I made the test regularly as I read also regularly that O3 is not necessarly better. I never met the case where O3 was slower and never met a compiler bug. I guess it depends on the type of programmes. Effectively I always work with float numbers. My colleagues made the same conclusion. In short, you have to measure each time

Comment: @Damien I read the documentation, and it looks like O1 O2 and O3 are levels of optimization but it's unclear to me when it's appropriate / wrong to use any of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just briefly:

The C++ version explicitly creates many new matrix objects and vectors. The python version is probably much more efficient behind the scenes.

To improve the performance of the C++ version (without changing the algorithm itself) we could:

- Create a single `vector<int>` for the results, and pass it by reference to `get_spiral`. We can add to it with `push_back` or `insert`.
- Instead of copying a subsection of the matrix, we could adjust and pass a simple bounds struct to the next recursive call:

  ```
  struct bounds { std::size_t x, y, w, h; };
  ```